# Google Sign in page pop is blank

Tags: reactjs, google-oauth

I am trying to create a basic login page for my social media website using Google OAuth but whenever I click the sign in with google button, the google sign in page does pop up but its all blank and in the console I have these two errors.(I new at react and this is my first time creating something with react)
[Errors in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0M1Gc.png)
[Blank Google Sign in page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhEiE.png)

```
import React from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { FcGoogle } from 'react-icons/fc';
import shareVideo from '../assets/share.mp4';
import ProjectLogo from '../assets/ProjectLogo.png';
import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from '@react-oauth/google';
import { GoogleLogin, googleLogout } from '@react-oauth/google';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
import { client } from '../client';

const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const createOrGetuser = async (response) => {
      const decoded = jwt_decode(response.credential)
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(decoded))
      const { name, email, picture, sub } = decoded;
      const doc = {
          _id: sub,
          _type: 'user',
          userName: name,
          image: picture,
      }
      client.createIfNotExists(doc)
      .then(() => {
          navigate('/', { replace: true })
      })

    }
  return (
    <div className='flex justify-start items-center flex-col h-screen'>
      <div className='relative w-full h-full'>
        <video 
          src={shareVideo}
          type= "video/mp4"
          loop
          controls={false}
          muted
          autoPlay
          className='w-full h-full object-cover'
        />
      </div>
      <div className='absolute flex flex-col justify-center top-0 bottom-0 left-0 right-0 bg-blackOverlay'>
        <div className='flex justify-start items-center flex-col c-screen'>
          <img src={ProjectLogo} width="130px" alt='logo' />
        </div>
        <div className='shadow-2xl flex justify-start items-center flex-col c-screen'>
          
          <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId={`${process.env.REACT_API_GOOGLE_API_TOKEN}`}>
            
            <GoogleLogin
               onSuccess={(response) => createOrGetuser(response)}
               onError={() => console.log('Error')}
               //cookiePolicy="single_host_origin"
            />

          </GoogleOAuthProvider>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

I tried everything I have found on internet to setup the login page but it just doesnt work.

Comment: If the answer helps, please choose the answer. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.
I added http urls in google cloud console.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6OCG.png

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Client id is undefined because in Nextjs if you want to get var from `.env` file you must put `NEXT_PUBLIC` to first of var. In this case you can get that var globally and publicly.

Change the var in `.env` to this:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_REACT_API_GOOGLE_API_TOKEN=the_api_token
```

and call it like this:

```
const NEXT_PUBLIC_REACT_API_GOOGLE_API_TOKEN = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_REACT_API_GOOGLE_API_TOKEN
```